# Varbinary update attempt

Tags: sql-server-2012, query, varbinary

Is it possible to adapt this into update query which has to seek a free sequence of 3 bytes or (0x000000) and replace it with a new sequence if the data is split like this every 3 bytes? The issue is that cast/replace wont work with undefined data which is 0x00.
The varbinary data is divided every 3bytes -> data(3bytes long)data(3bytes long).

```
DECLARE @YourTable table
(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Val VARBINARY(50)
)

INSERT @YourTable
VALUES (1, 0x0329000414000B14000C14000D0F00177800224600467800473C00550F00000000000000000000000000),
       (2, 0x0329002637000B14000C14000D0F00177800224600467800473C00550F00000000000000000000000000);


SELECT Id, Triplet
FROM @YourTable T
JOIN (VALUES (1),(4),(7),(10),(13),(16),(19),(22),(25),(28),(31),(34),(37),(40),(43),(46),(49)) Nums(Num) ON Num <= DATALENGTH(T.Val)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(T.Val, Num, 3))) V(Triplet)
WHERE Triplet = 0x000000 and DATALENGTH(Triplet) = 3
```

What I've tried:

```
UPDATE x    
set  x.column =  CAST(REPLACE(x.column, 0x000000, 0xFFFFFF) AS VARBINARY)
from Table as x
```

Works only if the column contains no data.

```
UPDATE x    
set  x.attr =  CAST(REPLACE(0x000000, 0x000000, 0xFFFFFF) 
from Table as x
```

This one semi works by replacing the first 3 bytes of the data, but I'd prefer not to lose data in the process.

The goal is to replace sequence of empty data in varbinary(50) with sequence of my desire. Or select a specific location of the binary for example the last plausible triplet location and import/replace the data there with the desired sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the question, you want to replace the leftmost occurrence of three zero bytes with `0xFFFFFF`:

```
DECLARE 
    @ToFind binary(3) = 0x000000,
    @ReplaceWith binary(3) = 0xFFFFFF;

UPDATE YT
SET Val = SUBSTRING(YT.Val, 1, CI.pos - 1) + 
    @ReplaceWith + 
    SUBSTRING(YT.Val, CI.pos + 3, 2147483647)
FROM @YourTable AS YT
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(@ToFind, YT.Val))) AS CI (pos)
WHERE
    CI.pos > 0;

SELECT YT.Id, YT.Val 
FROM @YourTable AS YT
ORDER BY YT.Id;
```

[*db<>fiddle* online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RqHyiQsV)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by running through every possible substring in order until you find a match. Then piece together the new binary value using `SUBSTRING`.

I have used a `Nums` function to generate the correct amount of rows. There are a number of different versions of this function out there, see https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1 You can also utilize an actual numbers table, and in SQL Server 2022 you can use `GENERATE_SERIES`

```sql
UPDATE t
SET Val = SUBSTRING(Val, 1, v.Num - 1) + 0xFFFFFF + SUBSTRING(Val, v.Num + 3, DATALENGTH(Val))
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      Nums.Num
    FROM dbo.Nums( CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(t.Val) > 2 THEN DATALENGTH(t.Val) - 2 END ) Nums
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (SUBSTRING(T.Val, Num, 3))) V(Triplet)
    WHERE V.Triplet = 0x000000
    ORDER BY
      Nums.Num
) v;
```

If the column is declared as `varbinary(max)` then you can use the little-known [`.WRITE` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#updating-lobs) to do this.

```sql
UPDATE t
SET Val.WRITE(0xFFFFFF, v.Num - 1, 3)
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      Nums.Num
    FROM dbo.Nums( CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(t.Val) > 2 THEN DATALENGTH(t.Val) - 2 END ) Nums
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES( SUBSTRING(T.Val, Nums.Num, 3) )) V(Triplet)
    WHERE V.Triplet = 0x000000
    ORDER BY
      Nums.Num
) v;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/hck56efW)

Note that this can only be done once per row, per `UPDATE` statement, you cannot do multiple replacements.

Comment: I can't get it to work outside the example db, the issue is that clearly I'm not using the function that you created as intended. I haven't changed the function, but clearly I'm doing it wrong.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Nums, Line 14

I've tried to register the function outside the query then i got:


Msg 258, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Cannot call methods on varbinary
and Nums.Num could not be bound.

Comment: Specify the schema for example `dbo.Nums`